# sys.indexes contains a row per index or heap of a tabular object - what does it mean?

Tags: sql-server, index, metadata, heap, sql-server-2022

I know a `HEAP` is a table without a clustered index. But I'm not quite clear on the following definition from `sys.indexes`.

I understand that this system view contains row per index of a tabular object. But I get confused when I read, *"contains a row per index or heap."*

### Question

Why is the document using the word `heap` in the following definition, why per index **or** heap?

> Contains a row per index or heap of a tabular object.

Ref: [sys.indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 2):

A heap is a table without a clustered index. Because there is no ordering to the pages, it is a commonly accepted term to describe them. It can be confusing to people coming from other programming languages, where a heap refers to an entirely different type of entity.

Note that a table without a clustered index may have a nonclustered primary key, but the base object will still be a heap.

Adding a clustered index logically orders the table by the clustered index key(s).